# Confusion about the idoc tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

There is the [idoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idoc) tag, which has the info

> IDOC is a proprietary server site scripting language for WebCenter Content server, previously Oracle UCM, previously Stellent Content Managment Server

So this seems to be about the ["IDoc scripting language" by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wcc/WCCDV/about_idoc_script.htm#WCCDV10226), which is used primarily for the presentation of HTML templates and configuration settings.

But there also exists a file format similar but not equal to XML by the name [SAP "IDoc".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDoc)

While the tag clearly is referencing the IDoc scripting language, the tag itself looks like SAP's IDoc as it only says [idoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idoc). Therefore most posts contain also the tag [sap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap) to show the connection betweern SAP and its file format idoc.

Would it make sense change the tags and split their meaning? For example make a [idoc-sl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idoc-sl) / [idoc-scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idoc-scripting) for Oracle's idoc and keep the [idoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/idoc)-tag for SAP?

Or is there a connection between the two idocs that I am unaware of?

Comment: Found your question after noticing the same issue - I think the [tag:idoc] tag would be more suitable for SAP IDocs & that the confusion certainly needs to be resolved.